# Add PXButton in top Navbar

Tags: acumatica

How do I put a PXActionButton that I have created using the below code in top nav bar of Acumatica.

```
public override void Initialize()
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Base.PrimaryView))
            {

                Type primaryViewItemType = Base.Views[Base.PrimaryView].Cache.GetItemType();
                PXAction action = PXNamedAction.AddAction(Base, primaryViewItemType, "SubmitTicket", "Submit Ticket", TestClick);
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable TestClick(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            throw new PXException("Button clicked from graph" + Base.GetType().Name);
        }
```

[image]
I tried to edit in Menu.aspx inside Frames page. But it doesn't seem to be the right one.

Is there some way, that I can choose the top nav as container while adding the button via my code in PXGraphExtension?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen you are showing "PM3010PL" is a Generic Inquiry screen:
[image]

Generic Inquiries can't be customized using Acumatica Project Editor like the other regular screens such as project "PM301000". This applies to all screen ending with suffix "PL".

Editing Menu.ASPX is out of customization scope and strongly discouraged. To achieve what you want, I would create a new Custom Inquiry screen using template 'Grid (Grid View)' that is functionally equivalent to 'PM3010PL'. Since that screen would be a Custom Inquiry instead of Generic Inquiry you can extend the graph and screen to customize it like all other screens.

The trick to have the button appear at the top is to decorate the action event handler with 'PXProcessButton' attribute instead of 'PXButton':

```
  public class ProjectEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ProjectEntry>
  {
    public PXAction<PMProject> testBill;

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Test Bill", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXProcessButton(Tooltip = "Test Bill")]
    public virtual IEnumerable TestBill(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
      return adapter.Get();
    }
  }
```

Then you declare the action in the Customized screen (Button Actions->Edit ASPX), this is the part you can do with regular screens but can't do with Generic Inquiries:
[image]

The Action will then be displayed on top:
[image]

**EDIT:**
For the top most navigation bar (in blue in your screenshot), this is completely out of customization scope. You could work out something in ASP I guess but this can't be packaged in customization and will be rejected for customization certification process.

Comment: Thank you @HB_ACUMATICA for clearing this out. I'll be ok with the button positioned at the current place.